# Why doesn't git give me any conflicts?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I found a strange problem. I was testing a git repo and found in this situation.

I created a simple git repo and add a text file with the following content.

```
Hello Git..!

First Line
```

Committed as the initial commit.

Then I created a branch called "abc" from that commit and change the content of the file to below.

(abc) -> branch

```
Hello Git..!

First Line
Second Line
```

Committed. Then I checked out back to my master branch and change the file content to below.

(master) -> branch

```
Hi Git..!

First Line
```

Committed. Then I tried to merge "abc" branch into "master" branch. I thought it would give me a conflict, but it had successfully merged via **recursively** to below.

```
Hi Git..!

First Line
Second Line
```

What didn't it show any conflicts? I tried with several attempts sometimes if there is no empty line between like below,

```
Hello Git...!
First Line
```

then it shows that there is a conflict. I can't understand this. Someone please help me to understand this.

I searched as much as I can but I could not able to find a question or answer to solve my question.

I have uploaded the sample repo to GitHub. If someone clones it and try to merge, it can be reproduced.

https://github.com/Ranjith-Suranga/test-repo

Is there any way to force GIT to show conflicts? I know it is a strange question, no one needs conflicts to arise. But I don't like this happening too. Just imagine, this happens to my real code.

**Update**

---

Since most of the comments and answers are suggesting that there can not have any conflict like this. I had to update this answer.

Okay, let's go all of these above steps once again after removing the second empty line.

Here we go,

1. I created a simple git repo and add a text file with the following content. This time around no empty line between the first and second line.

```
Hello Git..!
First Line
```

Committed as the initial commit.

2. Then I created another branch called "abc" from that commit and change the content of the file to below. (again removing the empty line)

(abc) -> branch

```
Hello Git..!
First Line
Second Line
```

Committed.

3. Then I checked out back to my master branch and change the file content to below.

(master) -> branch

```
Hi Git..!
First Line
```

Committed.

4. Then I tried to merge "abc" branch into "master" branch. This time around it is going to say me there is a **merge conflict**.

If you don't trust me, here is the sample github repo
https://github.com/Ranjith-Suranga/test-repo2

The first one doesn't give any conflict, the second one almost the same except for that removed empty line, it gives conflict. **But the question is why?**

Comment: Why would there be a conflict?  You changed two separate lines on two branches.  Git would only give you a conflict if you modify the same lines (or range of lines) on separate branches and then try to merge.

Comment: @TylerMarshall Please see the updated question

Comment: I've added numbers to the steps in your update so that it's easier to refer to each one.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that *all* versions of your file contain an incomplete last line. When you add another line, this means that you not just *add* a line, but you also *remove* the incomplete line and then *add* two lines.

In your second try, when you merge the two branches, Git detects changes in adjacent blocks of text. Contrary to what you might think, the line reading

```
First Line
```

does in fact *not* remain unchanged because the final line break that is added in one branch counts as a modification of that line. Since you have modifications in adjacent lines coming from different branches, Git reports a merge conflict.

In your first try, have a blank line above the line reading `First Line`. This line acts as an anchor point that remains stable during the merge, so to say. It allows Git to clearly separate the changes coming from different branches into different blocks of text. Therefore, Git can consolidate the modifications automatically, without a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, no merge conflict will occure in that case because there's no conflict here, so let's say you have 4 lines, and 2 branches.

**case 1:** in first branch you modify Line(1), in the seconde branch you modify Line(1) and Line(2), **this isn't a conflict**

**case 2:** in first branch you modify line(1), in the seconde you modify line(1) only (you modify exactly the same lines) **this is a merge conflict**.

Try it by yourself and you will notice the difference.

Comment: @MAHFOUDHKERBOUDCHE Thanks for answering my question, but I don't think I find the correct answer that I am looking for, please see the updated question if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> What didn't it show any conflicts?

Probably because your change in the `master` branch was exactly the same as the one in the `abc` branch, up to the end of the "First Line" line. So there were no conflicting changes. If you'd instead changed the third line of the file to "Third Line" in one of the branches, then you'd have commits with two different changes on the same line, and there'd be a conflict. But if the changes are the *same*, then there's no problem.

> I tried with several attempts sometimes if there is no empty line between like below...then it shows that there is a conflict.

Sure. Now you've changed the second line in `master` to "First Line" and the third line to nothing, while `abc` has commits that differ on the second and third lines. Which one should `git` choose? There's no way to tell, so you have to resolve it. In the previous case, `git` doesn't have to choose between two options because they're both the same.

**Update:**

In step 1 of your update, you've created an initial commit with the file containing:

```
Hello Git..!
First Line
```

That's in the `master` branch. Then you go and create a new `abc` branch, adding a line. And then in step 3, you say you checked out `master` and changed the file to

```
Hello Git..!
First Line
```

and committed *that*. But that's exactly what should have been in `master` in the first place, so it's not clear what change your committing. It sounds like you have another commit in `master` that changes the file, or perhaps some stray white space characters.

**The bottom line is that `git` will tell you that there's a merge conflict when it can't figure out what to do when merging two files.** When that happens, it marks the file with `>>>>>`, `=====`, and `<<<<<` indicators and both versions of the changed region, so you should be able to see exactly what the conflict is. Different versions of `git` might even behave differently in terms of what they can or can't resolve automatically, or why.

Looking back at your original example, and at the Github repo you linked, it's easy to see why there's no conflict: the second commit in `master` and the second commit in `abc` affect *different lines*, and you can see it right in Github. Here's the change in commit 549009d in `master`:

[image: commit 549009d]

That obviously replaces line 1 of the file. Here's commit 462394b in branch `abc`:

[image: commit 462394b]

As you can see, that change doesn't touch line 1, and affects only line 3 (and adds line 4). So the changes are completely distinct, and `git` can apply them both without any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is because you've modified "First Line" on branch abc and git can't match it back to "First Line" on the master branch.  The change you made was that you added a newline character at the end of the line (shown [here](https://github.com/Ranjith-Suranga/test-repo2/commit/117fae3ffaf73e646a495b69d512834767ab44bf)).

Try it again but with an initial README that ends with a newline character.

Comment: Git thinks you've changed "First Line" to "Second Line" because of the matching missing newline character.  It also thinks you've inserted a new line with contents "First Line"

Comment: Thank you for your answer once again. But if that is the case then the same thing is in my first repo as well. [see here](https://github.com/Ranjith-Suranga/test-repo/commit/462394bd7ffac9472a849953d504325f23752bd5). **Why then it doesn't show any conflicts?**

Comment: In your first repo, git matches the blank line from one branch to the other.  In the second repo, because of the newline character business, there is no line to match at all, which results in a conflict.

Comment: For the first repo, you can think of the blank line as like a barrier.  Git knows changes happened above the line on master branch, and it knows changes happened below the line on branch abc.  Merging the two branches just means taking the changes from master for above the blank line and taking the changes from abc for below the blank line.  There is nothing special about a blank line.  There would also not be a merge conflict in the second repo if the README always ended with a newline.

Answer (score -1):

Git create conflicts when different users push commits into the repository. If you are using the same user to create conflicts, these will never appear.

Comment: I don't think this is true. I can create a conflict on my own with no help from anyone else.